# Why does pygame crashe when I run this function that displays a question to the screen and asks for an input?

Tags: python, pygame

The intention of the function is to ask the user for an input between two options to change a variable. When the function is called pygame opens but it just displays black and crashes. Without the function the code works fine.

```
def pick_board():
    global bo
    global bo1
    global bo2

    while 1:
        question = font.render('Which board would you like to solve? \n\n 1 or 2:', True, pg.Color('black'))
        screen.fill('white')
        screen.blit(question, (20, 20))
        events = pg.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_1:
                    bo = bo1
                    break
                if event.key == pg.K_2:
                    bo = bo2
                    break
```

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement in your code breaks the `for`-loop (event loop), but not the `while`-loop (input loop). Add a `wait_for_input` state variable and change the state when the key is pressed.
Additionally you have to update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip).

```py
def pick_board():
    global bo
    global bo1
    global bo2

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    question = font.render('Which board would you like to solve? \n\n 1 or 2:', True, pg.Color('black'))
    wait_for_input = True
    while wait_for_input:
        clock.tick(100)
        events = pg.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_1:
                    bo = bo1
                    wait_for_input = False
                if event.key == pg.K_2:
                    bo = bo2
                    wait_for_input = False

        screen.fill('white')
        screen.blit(question, (20, 20))
        pygame.display.flip()
```